# Android swipe view UI like Crumblyy

Tags: android, user-interface, swipeview

I came across this app called Crumblyy, I would like to know how do I do apps which have swipe view like cards swipe like that app? I am looking at developing a custom app for myself for flashcards which would have similar cards layout and with the swipe functionality. Any tips and tricks to achieve that would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some of these libraries :

1) https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

2) https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards

3) https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack

4) https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack

5) https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView

And by the way, you can always google(do some research, show some effort) before asking questions here else your questions will be down-voted.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the start mate.. yes got the point.. will Google. Will get back with more meaningful questions. :)